# Using free() and memory allocation in LinkedList C

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>'

typedef struct NodeClass {

    char lineThatContainsWord[100];
    int lineNumber;
    struct NodeClass *next;

} Node;

int main(void) {
    Node *head;
    head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node *tail = NULL;

    head->next = tail; /* sets head equal to NULL */
    strcpy(head->lineThatContainsWord,"hello");
    head->lineNumber = 5;
    free(head);

    head->next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head->next->next = NULL;
    strcpy(head->next->lineThatContainsWord,"hello2");
    head->next->lineNumber = 10;

    tail = head->next;
    free(tail);
    printf(tail->lineThatContainsWord);
    printf("\nlineNumber is %d",tail->lineNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

I assumed that by setting tail = head->next, it would print the values of the head->next node. However, this printed

```
hello2
lineNumber is 0
```

why was only lineThatContainsWord updated? Why was lineNumber not?

Answer (score 1):

You're causing undefined behavior because you access the memory that `head` and `tail` point to after you free the memory (when I tried your program I got a segmentation violation error, but you can't depend on this). Get rid of the `free(head);` and `free(tail);` lines, and the program will print:

```
hello2
lineNumber is 10
```

as you expect.

Comment: My assignment requires me to free the variables so I freed them after I printed and it worked. However, I read that freeing variables simply release the data that they are pointing to. What would be the point of freeing at all, if I release the data after I access it?

Comment: You free it when you're done using it, so that the memory can be used for something else.

Comment: Would it be very impractical for programmers to never free their structs? It would make their memory allocation inefficient, correct?

Comment: If the program runs for a long time, you'll eventually run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting the program should output when you deleted the node the data members you are going to output of?

I think you mean the following

```
Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));

head->next = NULL; /* sets next equal to NULL */
strcpy(head->lineThatContainsWord,"hello");
head->lineNumber = 5;

Node *tail = head;

tail->next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
tail->next->next = NULL;
strcpy(tail->next->lineThatContainsWord,"hello2");
tail->next->lineNumber = 10;

tail = tail->next;

printf(tail->lineThatContainsWord);
printf("\nlineNumber is %d",tail->lineNumber);

free( tail );
free( head );
```